# Connecting multiple database through java without hard coding db details in program

Tags: java, database, oracle, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

I would like to know the ways to connect the multiple databases via single java program without hard-coding db details(username/password) in the java properties file/java program.

The actual requirement is: I need to fetch the data from one database and need to insert into another database.

I used spring boot non-web application, i added both db details in properties file and fetching the details from the properties file. everything working as expected. now the challenge is should not hard-coded the db password in the properties file or anywhere in coding as part of security. I am not running this application in any webserver to add the database details in the server configuration also. I want to deploy in the Appworx chain and chain batch will call this java program and java program has to connect the databases.

Can any one of you guys, please suggest me any solutions for my requirement. Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to define your own `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

Comment: Needing data not to be hardcoded = 1) Needing config file(s). or 2) Needing runtime input. --- Everything after that is runtime handling/code.

Comment: Get your DB connection parameters from remote server or use remote `JNDI` datasource lookup.

Comment: You can also consider encrypting sensitive entries in application.properties with jasypt: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot

Comment: I am not running this application via app server. I want to call this java program as jar file via the Appworx batch process. I cannot use DSN and other option like encryption/decryption.

Comment: @kris_k How do we encrypt passwords of both databases ?